# Run RTRT test from command line

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, stderr, rtrt

We are using IBM Rational Test RealTime for unit testing of ANSI-C code. It's my job to tell a Jenkins server to run those tests automatically.

[Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSHUF_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.testrt.studio.doc/topics/tclirun.htm?lang=de) suggests what command line should be used:

```
studio -r <node>.{[.<node>]} <project_file> [-html <directory>]
```

Unfortunately running `studio -r` with any more parameter does not output anything to the console. If it does not do the intended unit testing job, it terminates immediately and gives no error message whatsoever. This is frustrating. The error class can be deduced from the exit code, but that is not really enough for troubleshooting.

Any idea where to find error output? I can not find any log file.

The detailed command line syntax [is described here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSHUF_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.testrt.studio.doc/ref/rstudio.htm?lang=de),
but this claims, what apparently is not true:

> All messages are sent to the standard error output device.

If it runs successfully missing console output can be tollerated, but if it fails to run the test, I really, really would like to see the stuff that is normally output into the RTRT main window. Note: a unit test that fails
e.g. on an assertion is counted as "successful" test run in this context.

Comment: why don't you just read the data in html report file ?

Comment: If studio.exe fails with exit code 0 for example because the RTP file is not found, the HTML is not generated. "RTP not found" would help, but nothing. If studio.exe fails with exit code 5 for example because the TDP failed to connect to the target, the HTML is generated and contains nothing except the time of execution. That does not help either. Output of the script that fails to do the ssh would help, but nothing...

Comment: jenkins cannot execute graphical applications (except with JNSL? JNSP?). You have to find a way to run the underlying `attolxxxx` commands.